# Can you find $\star$

Tags: visual

Where is the hidden star in the picture below?

[image]

Reference: Question is taken from a local book, Author: Emrehan Halıcı, [Akıl Oyunları](http://www.kitapyurdu.com/kitap/zeka-oyunlari-1/60996.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Absolutely, it's right here!

> Just form it out of the red lines 
>  [image]